# Type text inside a node in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I want to add functionality that allows you to edit text inside a node when you double click on it. Is this possible with Cytoscape? An example of this is in [mxgraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html).

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? mxGraph inserts a foreignObject tag. Thanks

Comment: Is this about cytoscape.js or cytoscape? With cytoscape.js it's easy to achieve.

Comment: This is indeed about cystoscope.js. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks.